# Primefaces Tree does not expand if you select a node first

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 2 and a backing bean to display the tree component in two different facelets pages. On the first page, the tree displays, expands, and I can select items from it just fine.

When I go to the second page, I can expand nodes if I first do not select one. Saying it a different way, I can select nodes after the tree is initially loaded but I am unable to expand any nodes once I select a node. Both pages use the same backing bean and p:tree tag definition as below. The only difference is what is being updated (update attribute). Not sure if that would be the issue but I get no errors in the console.

```
<p:tree id="orgTree" value="#{userAdminBean.orgTree}" var="node" dynamic="true" 
   nodeExpandListener="#{userAdminBean.onNodeExpand}" update="orgName,groupName,position"
   selectionMode="single" selection="#{userAdminBean.selectedOrgNode}"
   nodeSelectListener="#{userAdminBean.nodeSelectedInEditUserScreen}">
      <p:treeNode>
         <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
      </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Comment: Is the selection method being called on the server side?  Is the nodeSelectListener method being called on the serverside?  Are there are any script errors on the page?

Comment: nodeSelectListener is called and there are no script errors. Interestingly enough, I see the @PostConstruct method being called when I try to expand a node on the second page. This should be ajax and since my backing bean is ViewScoped, there should be no called to PostConstruct when I expand a node.

Comment: I found out expanding a node is not considered a postback because the JSF isPostback() method returns false when I try to expand one.